# I'm studying as an exchange student from the US to Quebec (Canada) for 4 months, but want to stay longer

Tags: visas, canada, quebec

So, I will be on exchange to Quebec (Montreal) from January to April 2018. That is, the trimester will last January through April. I have verified that I don't need a study permit, as I will not be there for more than six months, and I don't intend to work while I'm there.

However, I would like to stay for an extra month if I'm there, or stay the whole six months. As I understand it, the border officer will decide the length of my studies:

> A border services officer at the port of entry in Canada will determine how long you can stay in Canada. Most visitors are allowed a six-month stay from the day they entered Canada. If the officer authorizes a stay of less than six months, they will indicate in your passport the date by which you must leave Canada.

Would anyone happen to know what circumstances would arise that I'm only allowed the 4 months? I know my home university won't be regulating my stay, and neither will UQAM.

As an American, I do not need an eTA or visa for a stay of under six months.

Edit: to clarify, I will not be moving here permanently. I will only be on exchange for one trimester (4 months).

Edit 2: trimester, not semester.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Questions related to long-term moves, particularly for work or study, may get better answers at http://expatriates.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @NateEldredge on the other hand, questions related to temporary stays under visa-free regimes available to short-term visitors from specific countries may get better answers here.

Comment: I may have misunderstood something and maybe I'm just wildly confused, but...how can a trimester and a semester last 4 months?

Comment: @motoDrizzt Sorry, I gave some inconsistent info that I'll edit. At the school I'll be attending, they use trimesters. This specific trimester will last 4 months. I myself am not used to the trimester system because my university uses semesters, which last for around 4 months as well. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Israel: hey, I was just joking! :-D The point was that everything made no sense at all to me, as trimester exact meaning is "three months" while semester exact meaning is "six months", and a period of four months is a "quadrimester", so I found all of this rather amusing. All those terms comes from Europe, from Latin language to be precise, so I had to do some research and discovered that the US education system uses them in a really amusingly and astonishingly incorrect way with the meanings "a third" and "a half" :-DD

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I never thought about it, we definitely don't use it correctly in US. We have...three semesters, technically. One spring, one fall, and one summer. Québec does the same, at least theirs matches up with "tri"! :)

Comment: @Israel I would like to know the outcome of your situation I am in a similar plan for September and would like to know how the stay time is determined.